# Appropriate way of Averaging an infinite rate or ratio

Tags: usability

Something that I haven't been able to get my head around is a case where an average measure is needed, but one of the rate or ratio inputs could be divided by 0. Allow me to explain:

Suppose we have a pass-to-fail ratio defined in a floating point datatype container: `pass / failures`.

If we have 0 passes, the average that is computed would be summed with 0. But if we have greater 1 pass and 0 failures, our floating point average will either be summed with `positive infinity`, `NaN`, or throw an exception.

A real world example of this possibility is the average kill-death ratio counter found in most video games where a player could go 14-0 for example.

---

### Pass-to-fail ratio:

*This dataset infers that there are a total of 7 tests.*

- 3/5
- 5/3
- 0/7
- 7/0

**AVG: Infinity**

[Source code runnable for example here](https://ideone.com/TD1t1f)

How would we resolve this situation to have a meaningful measure of average?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to User Experience? Nevertheless, you're analyzing two separate kinds of data here, KILL and DEATH, first get the average of kills, then the average of deaths, later on you can find the ratio from both averages.

Comment: There may be more relevant information on the [Wikipedia page for ratios and fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Notation_and_terminology). It explores many forms of notation and terminology for ratios, with examples.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc I was trying to decide between this and mathematics exchange. I ultimately decided on UX because I wanted to potentially get a more end-user oriented answer if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already learned, arithmetic average is not always the correct way of aggregating values.

What is the expected interpretation of the number you want to calculate?

Consider another example: fuel consumption:

- Monday: 50 km 3 liters
- Tuesday: 50 km 4 liters
- Wednesday: 0 km 2 liters (the cars was stuck in the mud)

Average fuel consumption per 100 km was: 6 / 8 / INFINITY!

But the real useful value of the combined week performance obtained by adding individual days is simply: 9 liters / 100 km

And this is what produces meaningful “average” in your example:

- total pass: 3+5+7=15
- total fail: 5+3+7=15
- pass-to-fail ratio: 15/15

Comment: I suppose we still have to deal with the case where everything passes, in which case infinity could be resolved to "All tests pass" state. Since both answers were largely the same I decided to accept this one b/c it had more examples and depth.

Answer (score 2):

Usually pass / fail ratio is presented as a percentage of passes (or failures), such as

> - 75 % of tasks failed
> - 25 % of tasks passed

In your case this would be:

```
2/5  28.6 % of tasks passed / 71.4 % of tasks failed
5/2  71.4 % of tasks passed / 28.6 % of tasks failed
0/7  0 % of tasks passed / 100 % of tasks failed
7/0  100 % of tasks passed / 0 % of tasks failed
```

Over all tests there are 14 passes and 14 failures out of 28 tasks, which means that on average 50 % of tasks passed / 50 % of tasks failed.